# Pandas str() method returns nan values - how to keep numeric values?

Tags: python, pandas, string

probably a trivial question: I have a pandas dataframe and a column with mixed dtypes. I would like to run various string methods on the column items, e.g. `str.upper()`, `str.lower()`, `str.capitalize()` etc. It works well for just string values in the column, however with numeric values (int/float) I get `nan`.

Example with `str.upper()`:

`output_table.iloc[:,0] = input_table.iloc[:,0].str.upper()`

- Justtext -> JUSTTEXT
- Textwith500number -> TEXTWITH500NUMBER
- 500 -> nan
- -11.6 -> nan

As the dataframe can become quite large (> 1m rows) I would like to have a fast routine to convert the input column by means of the respective string methods. How can I keep the numeric values untouched as they were (not returning nan) and only convert the string values? Something along the lines of pandas `errors='ignore'`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have numeric data mixed: convert to string then call upper: `input_table.iloc[:,0].astype(str).str.upper()` ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'desc': ['apple', "Textwidh500number", 500, -11.6]})

df["desc"] = [i.upper() if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in df["desc"]]

print (df)

                desc
0              APPLE
1  TEXTWIDH500NUMBER
2                500
3              -11.6
```

Comment: Thanks! Could performance be an issue here in your opinion? Compared to the answer by anky, i.e. use `.astype(str)`

Comment: Tested it with 1m dummy records, list comprehension is 2x faster @pythoneer.

Comment: Yes, astype and str methods are expensive :)

Comment: Oh wow, great!! Thank you very much, will give list comprehension a definitive go

Comment: Quick follow-up question: how would you concatenate multiple string methods on the same column like `capitalize()` ,`strip()` and `replace()` via a list comprehension?

Comment: My take: `df["desc"] = [i.capitalize().strip() if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in df["desc"]]` for the first two methods followed by `df["desc"] = [re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", i) if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in df["desc"]]` - it is working for the moment, maybe you have a way to improve performance. Thanks!

Comment: You can stick to what you are doing. Calling multiple str methods is a price you have to pay whether in list comprehension or using `pandas` str methods.

Answer (score 2):

I just did something similar with `pd.to_numeric` and passing `errors='coerce'` and `.notnull()`. Try this:

```
input_table.loc[(pd.to_numeric(input_table['Col_Name'], errors='coerce').notnull()),'Col_Name'].str.upper()
```